# Update select2 option text on-the-fly?

Tags: jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I want to change an option's text on the fly. The HTML can be changed easily by:

```
$('option[value=custom-pub]').text("New Text For Pub");
```

How can I force select2 to refresh the text? I don't want to `destroy()` and create the select2 object from scratch, because I want the user selection to stay selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
$("select").select2();
```

works.

Comment: This rebuilds the whole select2 control, and resets any supplied option beforehand, either resupply the options, or don't use this